# diplaying output of mutliple logs in the same terminal instance

Tags: linux, filter, tail

I am trying to find flow of a request in my application.I have multiple components that are responsible for handling that request.

For instance I have 4 components and I want to display all the logs in the same terminal instance to check the flow of the request. How can I achieve that?

Currently I am displaying all logs in different terminal instances like this.

```
tail -f path-to-log/component1.log
tail -f path-to-log/component2.log
```

I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Did you try `tail -f component1.log component2.log`?

Comment: I just tried.It was so simple. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, I just created an answer. Please accept it so that future readers can see the answer at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
tail -f component1.log component2.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/). It allows you to tail multiple files at the same time.